# FargmentTransaction is not working

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my code, I want to switch `fragments` through `ImageView` onClick. I wrote the code for it but my app closes if I click on the image.

```
public class FragHome extends Fragment {
ImageView frag_load;
ImageView frag_trucks;
ImageView frag_drivers;
ImageView frag_tracking;
ImageView frag_profile;
ImageView frag_history;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_home, container, false);

   frag_load = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnload);
    frag_trucks = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btntrucks);
    frag_drivers = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btndrivers);
    frag_tracking = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btntracking);
    frag_profile = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnprofile);
    frag_history = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnhistory);

    frag_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragCategory FC=new FragCategory();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("type","load");
            FC.setArguments(b);
            FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragload,FC,"load");
            ft.addToBackStack("load");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    frag_trucks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragCategory FC=new FragCategory();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("type","trucks");
            FC.setArguments(b);
            FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragtrucks,FC,"trucks");
            ft.addToBackStack("trucks");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    frag_drivers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragCategory FC=new FragCategory();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("type","drivers");
            FC.setArguments(b);
            FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragdrivers,FC,"drivers");
            ft.addToBackStack("drivers");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    frag_tracking.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragCategory FC=new FragCategory();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("type","tracking");
            FC.setArguments(b);
            FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragtracking,FC,"tracking");
            ft.addToBackStack("tracking");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    frag_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragCategory FC=new FragCategory();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("type","profile");
            FC.setArguments(b);
            FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragprofile,FC,"profile");
            ft.addToBackStack("profile");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });
    frag_history.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragCategory FC=new FragCategory();
            Bundle b=new Bundle();
            b.putString("type","history");
            FC.setArguments(b);
            FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fraghistory,FC,"history");
            ft.addToBackStack("history");
            ft.commit();
        }
    });

    return view;
}}
```

I think to know if the problem is with the id given in the `fragment` but all the id are correct.
It does not show any error in the monitor but the app closes after a few seconds.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnload"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/load"
                android:clickable="true"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Find Load"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btntrucks"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/trucks"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="My Trucks"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btndrivers"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/driver"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Drivers"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btntracking"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/tracking"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Tracking"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnprofile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/profile"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnhistory"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:src="@drawable/history"
                android:clickable="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="History"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

THere is no error shown in the logcat.

Comment: please add error log and your xml

Comment: Use `getChildFragmentManager()` is container is `Fragment`. and Why are using different container layout for each fragment ?

Comment: if you are unable to get the error from Logcat, then use Slpunk mint library to get the errors mailed to you... otherwise , simply check the error in logcat, it is most probably a null point Exception.

Answer (score -1):

The signature for replace function as per [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) is

```
replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)
```

where the first parameter is containerViewId where you should pass Fragment Container Layout Id You have passed ImageView ID which is not the container.

```
ft.replace(R.id.fragtrucks,FC,"trucks");
```

Comment: Where do you see that R.id.fragtrucks is an ImageView?